# Ansible error message

Tags: ansible, devops

I'm trying to use ansible to build a docker image locally but I'm
running into problems.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Build Docker image
      local_action:
          module: docker_image
          path: .
          name: SlothSloth
          state: present
```

And my /etc/ansible/hosts contains

```
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

But when I try to run it I get:

```
TASK: [Build Docker image] **************************************************** 
failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
failed=True msg='failed to import python module: No module named docker.client'


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: Have you installed docker-py on your machnine?

Comment: No, I installed it and now i get failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
failed=True msg='failed to import python module: No module named urllib.parse'. And urllib is already installed.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. That library is standard with Python....Try to reinstall Python: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpython2.7-stdlib`

Comment: I tried to do yum python reinstall but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as your parent one, except docker-py is installed.  I'm using a virtualenv.  If I run the interpretor, it sees the module.  But if I run ansible, no docker.client module.  I also tried instlaling docker-py globally, in which case it works.  I can't figure out why ansible (which, itself, is running from virtualenv) can't find the modules in the virtualenv.

Comment: Oops...the ansible_python_interpreter thing works, if you don't fat-finger it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using virtualenv, you are probably running ansible with /usr/bin/python by default. To bypass this behavior, you have to define the variable "ansible_python_interpreter".

Try to use :

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - ansible_python_interpreter: python
  tasks:
    - name: Build Docker image
      local_action:
          module: docker_image
          path: .
          name: SlothSloth
          state: present
```